# WP_Query with MetaQuery issue

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm facing a rather strange issue when attempting to pass in four different meta_query values to my WP_Query.

Find below an example of my WP_Query search. Please bear in mind, if I remove and test each of these meta_query on there own, they work fine. It's just when they are being passed in as four do I not get any results. Even if I leave the values blank I still receive no posts in my query!

```
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'loads_available',
    's'             =>  "Post Name", 
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
      array(
            'key'     => 'type_of_load',
            'value'   => "Frozen",
            'compare' => '=',
          ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'number_of_pallets',
            'value'   => 2,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'

          ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'type_of_trailer_required',
            'value'   => "Trailor",
            'compare' => '=',
          ),
          // ^ problem
        array(
            'key' => 'euro_pallets',
            'value' => "Yes",
            'compare' => '='

            )
        )
    );

    $loadsAvailableQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );
```

Now I would just like to make it clear, these meta_query values work fine on a individual basis, it's just when I start trying to use them in conjunction with each other for example.

Search query would be:

Post Name: "Post Name"
Type of Load: "Frozen"
Number of Pallets: 5
Type of Trailor Required: "Trailor"
Euro Pallets: "Yes"

This would not give me any results, even though I am sure there is posts meeting the criteria. It's feels like I could be missing something in the Query, I read about use relation but that defaults to "OR" - which I believe would be the correct value here.

Are there any common misconceptions or obvious flaws in my code that I'm not quite seeing here?

Many thanks for the responses.

Comment: Does it work if you use any 2 (or 3) together?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I can use 2 at the same time anymore and it just doesn't load results (yet there are results available...) even if the value is empty

Comment: So you mean it fails if you use any 2 together? Do any posts satisfy both (or all) conditions? Did you try setting `'relation' => 'OR'`?

Comment: Ideally, I want the relation to be AND because I want the query to match all of the search values.

Comment: Yes but you're in a debug situation here so trying OR could lead you to see what data is matching and whether it meets your expectations ... also it might be worth doing a `var_dump($loadsAvailableQuery->request);` after the `new` and running the query directly against the database (via mysql shell or phpAdmin or whatever)...

Comment: Ok - what should I be looking for then? If there are posts? But If there are surely they should be showing..

Comment: And if there aren't?! Basically I'm guessing that your expectations and the data don't match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try adding the `'RELATION' =>` parameter into your meta query array so that you can encompass all of your meta values. Something like this:

```
    $v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'loads_available',
    's'             =>  "Post Name", 
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
            'key'     => 'type_of_load',
            'value'   => "Frozen",
            'compare' => '=',
          ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'number_of_pallets',
            'value'   => 2,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'

          ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'type_of_trailer_required',
            'value'   => "Trailor",
            'compare' => '=',
          ),
          // ^ problem
        array(
            'key' => 'euro_pallets',
            'value' => "Yes",
            'compare' => '='

            )
        )
    );

    $loadsAvailableQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );
```

Depending on your use case, you may need to set up a variable based on the user query to toggle the relation parameter in your query.

Note the relation parameter can also be set to `'OR'`.

Checkout the meta_query section inside of the [WP_Query codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: `AND` is the default relation. This code does nothing different that he original code. ["This construct allows you to query multiple metadatas by using the relation parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the meta queries. Accepted arguments are 'AND', 'OR'. The default is 'AND'.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Just read this too - what else could be a problem with the code then?